# EntityManagerFactory is initialing

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hikaricp, entitymanagerfactory

I`m DONT use EJB/Spring etc.

Only Jpa + Servlet.

I`m trying to create

public abstract class AbstractEntityManagerFactory {

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateTask");

public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

When I run it through

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

It works well.

But if using TomCat 9.0.58 - I get an error:

```
05-Apr-2022 22:58:58.985 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider]
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close()" because "this.hds" is null
        at org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider.stop(HikariCPConnectionProvider.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:390)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.cleanup(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1449)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at com.aimprosoft.hopak.factory.AbstractEntityManagerFactory.<clinit>(AbstractEntityManagerFactory.java:9)
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="HibernateTask">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Departments"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.password" value="ISBN97859910"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout" value="20000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="150000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.poolName" value="HikariPool"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hikari.autoCommit" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maxLifetime" value="90000"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using...

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Departments"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
```

...instead of `hibernate.hikari.*` properties. That helped in my setup.